# Can Nginx make hash sum from some strings (unique Request Id)?

Tags: nginx, hash

I found this [sbange's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24910594/1929406) about unique request ID in nginx upstreams.
Here is a quote:

```
location / {
      proxy_pass http://upstream;
      proxy_set_header X-Request-Id $pid-$msec-$remote_addr-$request_length;
  }
```

It's looks nice, but it generates long and not very useful string. It would be better with a short hash (md5 for example).

Then I found this third-party [nginx module ngx_http_set_hash](https://github.com/simpl/ngx_http_set_hash). And of course, I can use a perl_modules for md5 functions. But, I trying to find some out-of-box, just with Nginx.

Can Nginx make hash value of some string or maybe someone know better method for generating short unique request id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new [$request_id](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables) variable now is available since Nginx v1.11.0.